# How many tuples in one batch is reasonable in Storm?

Tags: apache-storm

I am a newbie of Storm. When I try trident with the tutorial example, they are usually a very small amount of tuples in one batch(usually no more than 10).
Trident aim to provide a high throughput,says millions of message per second. 
So I want to ask how many tuples in one batches is reasonable in real world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight forward answer to that question. It all depends on your workload and what kind of topology you are running. Once you have a desired topology, you can look at the overall throughput metrics and keep on bumping up the batch size till you start seeing some performance issues and debug that. If it's just due to the way your processing is structured and you cannot improve it any further then you can settle for a batch size smaller than that.

From:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/storm-user/IfMR-kHvkBg